# Removing Unicode Replacement Characters from String

Tags: android, database, string, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an Android (Java) app that reads values from a BLE device and stores them in a database. This works pretty well, except that for some characteristics that I read and get the String value of, the String includes random replacement characters (�). If I ignore them the String is normal, but these characters cause problem when working with my database.

How can I remove any replacement characters like that from my Strings?

EDIT: I tried using regex to replace any replacement characters, and another replaceAll to replace anything that wasn't a standard character, but none of those seemed to work. But when I output the strings in a TextView, for some reason these characters are gone?

Comment: You should not replace them. You probably read in bytes in a byte array. You should convert that byte array to string using the right encoding.

Comment: Weirdly enough I tried that but I still got the replacement characters. Since the BLE hardware isn't mine, maybe there's something wrong with the hardware and I just don't know about it. I ended up writing a method that creates a new String with only legal characters - it's definitely not ideal but it works for now until I can get in touch with the developers. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: I found out that the problem was not with my code, but with the device itself. The characteristics I was reading from were defined as Strings but whoever programmed them onto the device was not encoding them as Strings. So the conversion failed because the bytes received did not correspond to any Unicode characters. So my solution was to still replace any illegal characters in case this happened again.